# Storing Long numbers in arduino like phone numbers...How?

Tags: arduino-ide

I am using 20 x 4 LCD And 3 x4 keypad I want to enter and store 3 inputs in different variables the code I am using can store 3 inputs and display it right in serial monitor example I type 5 digits using keypad it will store and display correctly in LCD and serial monitor the right value however if its more than five it has negative output and very far to what inputted. Thank you for help .The code is...  [image][image]

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(6,5);
#include <Keypad.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 3; //three columns

char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3'},
  {'4','5','6'},
  {'7','8','9'},
  {'*','0','#'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {19, 18, 17, 16}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {15, 14, 13}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

int count=0;
Keypad kpd = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);

char entryStr[12];   // This can hold up to 4 digits
int i=0;

void setup()
{
    mySerial.begin(9600); 
    Serial.begin(9600);
    lcd.begin(20, 4);
}

void loop(){
    long n1, n2 , n3;

    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Enter n1:   "); 

    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    n1 = GetNumber();
    Serial.println ("n1: ");
    Serial.println (n1);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Enter  n2:   "); 

    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    n2= GetNumber();
    Serial.println ("n2: ");
    Serial.println (n2);  
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Enter n3:   "); 
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    n3 = GetNumber();
    Serial.println ("n3: ");
    Serial.println (n3);  
}

int GetNumber()
{
    long num = 0;
    char key = kpd.getKey();
    while(key != '#')
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case NO_KEY:
            break;

            case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
            case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
            lcd.print(key);
            num = num * 10 + (key -'0');
            break;

            case '*':
            num = 0;
            lcd.clear();
            break;
        }
        key = kpd.getKey();
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Phone numbers should be handled as strings. Otherwise `1`, `01` and `000000001` will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int GetNumber()
```

should be changed to

```
long GetNumber()
```

It is because the function type is the type of value that returning. In this case you are returning a long so you have to change it. An int can handle a number from -32 768 to 32 767. A long on the other side can handle a number from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

Comment: thank you I followed what you advised it displayed the right value however if i tried to typed 091234 i can only see 91234 thank you very much I a newbie I appreciate your help a lot thanks

Comment: can be risky but use a char instead. the arduino sees your number as a litteral mathematical number. it will simplify your number by removing the 0s like when you do a calculation in math. please dont tell me you do 0003 x 0009 = 0027. using a char is like sending a complete word like HELLO then you can decompose it into multiple small bits such as H, E, L, L, O,. It also works with numbers like if your password was 0192, you can decompose it to 0_1_9_2

Comment: Thank you I'll try what you advices thank you again I appreciated your help and sharing your time thank you .

Comment: its char* btw. char is different then char* dont forget the *